# JetPack Compose Hide View after interactions stop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to hide a view after interactions have stopped. I have the following which will hide the view after a given period, but if there are any interactions whilst this period is occurring I would like the hide timer to be reset. What is the best way of implementing this?

```
        var controlsVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        if (controlsVisible) {
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                delay(CONTROLS_HIDE_DELAY)
                controlsVisible = false
            }
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                .clickable { controlsVisible = true },
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(controlsVisible) {
                TopControls(viewModel, displayColor)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Launched effect with an incrementing key works!

The launched effect gets cancelled and so does it's coroutine scope.

```
        var controlsVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        var touchCounter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(1) }

        LaunchedEffect(touchCounter) {
            delay(CONTROLS_HIDE_DELAY)
            controlsVisible = false
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                .clickable {
                    controlsVisible = true
                    touchCounter++
                },
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(controlsVisible) {
                TopControls(viewModel, displayColor)
            }
        }
```